# Java: Check binary value with a mask then get integer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Here is my problem:

I have a binary value

```
101001
```

and a mask

```
011100
```

I would like to compare them and get the result as an integer. In this case that would give:

```
 1 **010** 01
 0 **111** 00

= 010 => 2
```

My first idea consists of dealing with a character array. But I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this aim in Java?

Comment: but it's not 2, the result of applying the mask would be `01000` - unless I'm missing some logic that you are aware of..

Comment: I agree. But in my case I need to get 2. It may not be a bitmask, I'm sorry if I did use the right words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just improved the algorithm to be able to have mask where one bits can be splitted such as:

```
00111011011
```

Here is my function to get a value from a mask and a masked value

```
 private static long getMaskedValue(long maskedValue, long mask){
        long definitiveMaskedValue = 0;
        int count=0;

        maskedValue = mask & maskedValue;

        while (mask != 0){
            while ((mask & 1) == 0){
                mask = mask >>> 1;
                maskedValue = maskedValue >>> 1;
            }
            while ((mask & 1) == 1){
                definitiveMaskedValue = definitiveMaskedValue + ((maskedValue & 1) << count);
                count++;

                mask = mask >>> 1;
                maskedValue = maskedValue >>> 1;
            }
        }

        return definitiveMaskedValue;
    }
```

Here is my function to store a value in a variable thanks to a bitmask, it returns the old variable with the value stored inside. 
I had to use BigInteger because of the shift operator that can not shift more than 32bits left in Java.

```
private static long setMaskedValue (long maskedValue, long mask, long valueToAdd) {
            int nbZero=0;
            int nbLeastSignificantBit=0;
            long tmpMask=mask;
            maskedValue = maskedValue & ~mask;

            while (tmpMask != 0){
                while ((tmpMask & 1) == 0){
                    tmpMask = tmpMask >>> 1;
                    nbLeastSignificantBit++;
                    nbZero ++;
                }

                while ((tmpMask & 1) == 1){
                    tmpMask = tmpMask >>> 1;

                    BigInteger bigValueToAdd = BigInteger.valueOf(valueToAdd).shiftLeft(nbZero);
                    long tmpValueToAdd = bigValueToAdd.longValue();
                    BigInteger bigMaskOneBit = BigInteger.valueOf(1).shiftLeft(nbLeastSignificantBit);
                    long maskOneBit = bigMaskOneBit.longValue();

                    long bitValueToSet = getMaskedValue(tmpValueToAdd, maskOneBit);
                    maskedValue = maskedValue | bitValueToSet << nbLeastSignificantBit;
                    nbLeastSignificantBit++;
                }
            }
        return maskedValue;
    }
```

Comment: why using BigInt for a simple problem like that? Just a waste of resource. Handling a special corner case for shifting 32 bits is still much faster than doing BigInt's maths

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to compare them and get the result as an integer

Assuming you meant 'mask' rather than 'compare':

```
int result = 0B011100 & 0B011100;
```

No char arrays required.

This is rather trivial.

Comment: It won't return 010, though it's rather unclear why OP wants the result shifted.

Comment: not so simple: System.out.println("TEST: " +(28 & 41)); returns 8 ! (01000) instead of 2 (010)

Comment: Because you need to shift right to eliminate those 2 zeros ;-)

Comment: that's it ! It's seems obvious, but I never used shift operators before ;) thank you !

Comment: I deliberately mentioned the assumption I was working on. Clearly the OP has left something out of his question.

Comment: If you hadn't used shift, learn to use it. That's one of the basics in binary

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Your comment should be addressed to the OP. It has nothing to do with this answer.  FYI I've been using shifts since 1971.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

1. You need first AND your bits.
2. Shift right to avoid those zeros at right of mask.

You need value as integer already.

Then do the AND: `int masked = value & mask;`

Then shift right until the first 1 in the mask.

```
while (mask % 2 == 0) {
   mask = mask >>> 1;
   masked = masked >>> 1;
}
```

You can use `while (mask & 1 == 0) {` if you prefer :)

---

```
& is bitwise AND.
| is bitwise OR.
^ is bitwise XOR (if my memory doesn't fail :).
>>> is shifting right (unsigned integer)
```